# Equivalent to bcdiv from php in java

Tags: java, php, precision, division

What is the equivalent of `bcdiv(string, string [, int])` in `java`

the function divides two arbitrary precision numbers

I would like for instance to use:

`bcdiv(10000,100, 2)` results in **100.00**

or

`bcdiv(10000,100, 3)` result in **100.000**

I am more interested in the precision it gives.

I would like its equivalent in `java`

[link to the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` class allows arbritary precision math. In particular see the [divide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20int%29) method.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(10000);//Can take int
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100");//Or string
BigDecimal answer = a.divide(b);
```

Comment: it seems to be what I am looking for, any working example?

Comment: @william.eyidi I've added an example. The docs can provide more depth: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29

Comment: this is a great answer, but I would like to be able to apply it to a float or double without having to cast it to bigDecimal. I willl look for some work around before deciding on the answer thanks

Comment: and @Jim the example doesn't include a precision change

Comment: @william.eyidi, floats and doubles are already inherently imprecise in representing non-integer values.  You really don't want to use them at all for this sort of computation.

Answer (score 1):

The number has defined structure, but you can format String produced from this number:

```
String.format("%.2f",10000/100f);
```

Comment: What you recommend is to forma the string value, then converter back to `float` or `double`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it can work, but as I can see Jim's answer, his idea is much nicer @william.eyidi

Comment: yes sure this is very hard coded I would like something more flexible.